# Is there a way of centering a single <div> contents vertically without affecting the contents of the <div> sibling?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

[Image showing the expected alignment on the last div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnITv.png)  I have multiple div wrap around a parent with display set to flex. 
I want **to vertically align** (as in vertical-align:middle) **and** also **horizontally align** (as in text-align:center) **any content that will be put into the LAST div ONLY,** such as Privacy Policy, Terms of Use, social media buttons, etc without affecting other sibling which is currently displaying as expected.

I tried setting the parent to display as flex and setting both justify-content and align-items to center, but it affected all the children - not just the LAST DIV (which isn't what I want).

Using vertical-align:middle; doesn't seem to work either.

Here's the STYLESHEET:

```css
#footer-container{
        width:100%; min-height: 200px;
        background: lightblue; border:2px solid blue;
        }
        #div-wrap{
            display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content: space-between;

            font-size:1rem;
            width:95%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }
            #div-wrap div{
                border:2px solid red;
                min-width:200px; height: 200px;
                margin:4px auto; padding: 0 3px;
                display: inline-block; 
                font-size: 1.3rem;
                }
                h5{
                    font-size:1.125rem;
                    padding:5px;margin:0px;
                    }

 /*  The code below can be modified for the question...  */
            .terms{
                width: 300px; background-color: yellow;
                color:green; font-weight: bolder; text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle; /* Does;nt work, dont know why */
                margin-left: auto; margin-right: 6px;
                }
```

```html
<section id="footer-container">
             <div id="div-wrap" >

                <div>
                    <h5>Quick Link Title</h5>
                    <ul> </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h5>Quick Link Title</h5>
                    <ul> </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h5>Quick Link Title</h5>
                    <ul> </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h5>Quick Link Title</h5>
                    <ul> </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="terms" >

                    <p><small>Copywrite &copy;2019. All right reserved</small></p>

                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: I read your question multiple times and I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve. Plus, please format your code so it'll be easier for other people to help you.

Comment: thanks. please see the image I attached to the question and the code on codepen: https://codepen.io/Keleoswilliam/pen/yLBJrMy  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
#footer-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#div-wrap > div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 4px auto;
  padding: 0 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#div-wrap div.terms {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4px auto;
  padding: 0 3px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer div {
height: 70px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.icon {
margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<section id="footer-container">
  <div id="div-wrap">

    <div>
      <h5>Quick Link Title</h5>
      <ul> </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>Quick Link Title</h5>
      <ul> </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>Quick Link Title</h5>
      <ul> </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>Quick Link Title</h5>
      <ul> </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="terms footer">
     <div><span class='icon'>fb</span><span class='icon'>twitter</span><span class='icon'>other</span></div>
     <div><p><small>Copywrite &copy;2019. All right reserved</small></p></div>
     <div>Other info </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  That is exactly what I want to achieve, But i noticed that when I adds more content to the last div, it breaks the expected formatting.  UPDATE: I have included an image to my original question, depicting what I want to achieve...

Comment: @KeleosWilliam can you please update your code to replicate what exactly you are trying?

Comment: Thanks cccn, something like that. I'll try it out on codepen with the updated  code: https://codepen.io/Keleoswilliam/pen/yLBJrMy